# Django - The current path, job/all, matched the last one. - But it still returns 404

Tags: python, django

When I go to this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/all` I am always receiving a 404 error with this message:
[404 Django Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ha8A.png)

However, when I just go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000` it always finds the `/` (index) route correctly regardless if there is a trailing slash, or not. This issue seems to only happen with the `/job/WHATEVER_ELSE_GOES_HERE` URLs.

I have the following URLs setup:

My `jobs` app `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('job/<int:job_id>', job_details, name="job_detail"),
    path('job/all/', all_jobs, name="all_jobs"),
    path('job/add/', add_job, name="add_job"),
    path('job/my_posted_jobs/', my_posted_jobs, name="my_posted_jobs"),
    path('job/delete/<int:job_id>', delete_job, name="delete_job"),
    path('job/search', search_job, name="search_job"),
    path('job/apply_for_job/<int:job_id>', apply_for_job, name="apply_for_job")
]
```

My project's `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('jobs.urls')),
    path('user/', include('users.urls')),
    path('payments/', include('payments.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the error message (screenshot) it also says this:
`The current path, job/all, matched the last one.`

How come it matches a URL but returns 404?

How do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: `job/all` is not the same as `job/all/` (notice the trailing `/`) your url is incorrect.

Comment: In the path, you specifically configured `job/all/`, so it should always have the `/`. Did you want to support the url without `/`?

Comment: In case you don't want to bother with the slash: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash. Though it is cleaner to have the slash specified in your code

Comment: Thank you all. I have changed all my urls in my templates (like in the navbar, etc.) to use a trailing slash and this fixed the issue. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the "/" since you have included it in your syntax in your urls.py therefore call the url from your web browser using  the link below when you have started the Django web server.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/all/